# Nativescript 6 code sharing project and tns-platform-declarations: error during compilation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, code-sharing

I've created a new Nativescript Code Sharing Project following this page:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics TestProject --shared --style=scss
```

Then I've added the `tns-platform-declarations` following the steps in this page:

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript

But still when I try to use iOS specific classes (like NSString) it gives me an error on compilation:

```
error TS2552: Cannot find name 'NSString'.
```

In the old standard NS project it was working so it's possibly something related to the code sharing, what am I doing wrong?

This is a sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/66ve80jif3bf0qk/TestProject.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sometimes you might have to restart VSCode for newly added declarations to be effective, did you try that?

Comment: I have downloaded your code from dropbox and it is wring absolutely fine using vscode.

Comment: Thanks to both, I've restarted multiple times, also deleted the hooks, node_modules and platofrms directories...will try again and will let you know. @Narendra what version of NS are you using?

Comment: I've tried again with NS 6.0.3 but same result, what can I check to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you described. VS Code recognized the typings as expected but the build failed.

I solved the issue by including **reference.d.ts** in **tsconfig.tns.json**.

```
"files": [
"./reference.d.ts",
"src/main.tns.ts"
]
```